# My nav bar aren't being hover and the link doesn't work, why not?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, navbar, nav

my nav bars aren't being linked and also when I hover over them they won't work.

```
<header>
    <div class="row">
        <ul class="main-nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                <li><a href="blog.html">BLOG</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">STUDY</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">STUDY</a></li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

my CSS is this:

```
.row {
max-width: 1200px;
margin: auto;
    }
.main-nav {
float: right;
margin-top: 30px;
    }
.main-nav li {
display: inline-block;
    }
.main-nav li, a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 5px 20px;
font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
     }
 .main-nav li.active a {
border: 1px solid white;
     }
 .main-nav li a:hover {
border: 1px solid white;
background-color: darkorange;
     }
```

can you tell me what is wrong with this code
is it the part where it said .main-nav li a:hover.
Please I really need you what I can fix

Answer (score 1):

I have checked from my end and it seems the link to be  working fine. I am not sure why it doesn't work in your case. In the below snippet, I have made some changes to the **.main-nav** and **.main-nav li, a** class so that it looks good and clean than what you had before (clumpsy and sticky navbar). **Please run the code snippet for the result**. Hope you will find this helpful.

```css
.row {
max-width: 1200px;
margin: auto;
    }
.main-nav {
float: right;
margin-top: 30px;
background-color: #0066ff;
width:100%;
padding:7px;
    }
.main-nav li {
display: inline-block;
    }
.main-nav li, a {
color: white;
width:70px;
float:left;
padding:10px;
text-align:center;
text-decoration: none;

font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
     }
 .main-nav li.active a {
border: 1px solid white;
     }
 .main-nav li a:hover {
border: 1px solid white;
background-color: darkorange;
     }
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="row">
        <ul class="main-nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                <li><a href="blog.html">BLOG</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">STUDY</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">STUDY</a></li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </header>
```